# Sample rails4 application with REST API which uses paperclip to upload to Amazon S3

Tags: rest, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, paperclip

Can someone share me a sample application , that has REST APIs to upload images to Amazon S3 . I've googled a lot , but most of them are not working as expected .

A little help would be greatly appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For uploading images through API you can convert the images to **base64** format in front end and send it to server. In, server you can convert the base64 data into the image and save it to `S3` via `paperclip`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save :decode_picture_data, :if => :picture_data_provided?
    has_attached_file :avatar,
                    :storage => :s3, :s3_protocol => 'https',
                    :bucket => # S3_Bucket,
                    :url => '/user/:id/:basename_:id.:extension',
                    :s3_credentials => {
                        :access_key_id => # Access key id,
                        :secret_access_key => # Secret access key
                    },
                    :path => '/user/:id/:basename_:id.:extension',
                    :default_url => ""

  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => %w(image/jpeg image/jpg image/png)

  private

  def picture_data_provided?
    !self.picture_data.blank?
  end

  def decode_picture_data
    # If cover_image_data is set, decode it and hand it over to Paperclip
    data = StringIO.new(Base64.decode64(self.picture_data))
    data.class.class_eval { attr_accessor :original_filename, :content_type }
    data.original_filename = SecureRandom.hex(16) + ".png"
    data.content_type = "image/png"
    self.avatar = data
    self.picture_data = nil
  end
end
```

Here, `picture_data` is a column in `User` table which has the **base64** data received from the client through API `params`.

You can specify your own S3 `URL` and path in above code.

In the above code the `picture_data` that came from the client side is decoded and saved in `S3` via `Paperclip`.

Comment: Gokul , thanks for the reply . Can you please share me a sample app, so that I would get configs for paper clip , gems used etc .

Comment: Just follow the steps in paperclip github page nothing special I have done. https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#installation

Comment: Gokul , one more question , since base 64 encoding takes time at the client side , can I create a generic upload service using paper clip that handles it as a form-data  , as this would improve the performance a lot . My clients include iOS/Android apart from web . Please help me on this .