# Received Base64 string in Rails to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, base64, paperclip

From a SOAP call I've received a Base64 string that looks like this:

```
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
```

And this represents a pdf file that is a label-image for post-orders.

I have called every db-object that needs this label a run:

```
class Run < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :delivery
  belongs_to :invoice

  has_attached_file :label,
    :storage    => :s3,
    :bucket     => Figaro.env.s3_bucket,
    :s3_region  => 'eu-west-1',
    :s3_credentials => {
      :access_key_id      => Figaro.env.aws_access_key_id,
      :secret_access_key  => Figaro.env.aws_secret_access_key
    }
end
```

In my controller:

```
base_64_string = @response_label[:generate_label_response][:response_shipments][:response_shipment][:labels][:label][:content]
```

And I know I should use the Base64 class, something like this:

```
content = Base64.decode64 base_64_string
```

I know it is the actual label-pdf by trying to use a tempfile, but this seems less than ideal.

How would I best save it to S3 using the Paperclip gem? Going from this `base_64_string`...

Comment: [This stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40460056/sample-rails4-application-with-rest-api-which-uses-paperclip-to-upload-to-amazon/40460631#40460631) answer contains code to save image to S3 from base64 encoded string. You can try this by changing the content-type to `application/pdf'.

Comment: Thank you, it indeed worked. I find the saving of data both as the base64 string and on the s3 not very efficient. I guess when you delete the field on your own db it shouldn't be too much of a bug to me. Anyway glad this works.